# Javascript print in a new window won't display images

Tags: javascript, image, printing

I'am struggling with a problem and I was hoping you can help me. I created a function that prints out data from inputs in a page. However, logo I am using on a print page won't be displayed like as if a link to the image is broken. Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
function printReport() {
    win=null;
    var vin = $("input[name='vin']").val();
    var make = $("select[name='make']").val();
    var printData = '<table width="960" border="0" align="center"> <tr> <td colspan="2"><img src="http://localhost/site/images/logo_print.png" width="291" height="109" /></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2"><div class="print-title" align="center">Service report </div></td> </tr> <tr> <td width="196">Vin:</td> <td width="754"><b>'+ vin +'</b></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Make:</td> <td><b>'+ make +'</b></td> </tr> </table>';
    win = window.open();
    self.focus();
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<'+'html'+'><'+'head'+'><'+'style'+'>');
    win.document.write("body, td { height: 25px; font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 17px; color:#333333;} .logo{ background:url(http://localhost/clubdfrance/images/logo_print.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; display:block; width:291px; height:109px;} .print-title{ display:block; margin-top:10px; font-size: 25px; }");
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'style'+'><'+'/'+'head'+'><'+'body'+'>');
    win.document.write(printData);
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'body'+'><'+'/'+'html'+'>');
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
    win.close();
```

Comment: Maybe my answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007595/twitter-bootstrap-modal-inserting-a-background-image/39426574#39426574

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution for everyone out there who has this problem. Problem is with the browsers. They are designed not to print images like this in order to save printers ink. Walkaround for this problem is using **CSS media print** and **list-style-image**.

CSS:

```
@media all{
   printed-div{
       display:none;
   }
}

@media print{
   printed-div{
       display:block;
   }
   .logo-print{
       width:291px;
       height:109px;
       display: list-item;
       list-style-image: url(../images/logo_print.png);
       list-style-position: inside;
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="printed-div"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function printReport() {
    $(".printed-div").html();
    var vin = $("input[name='vin']").val();
    var make = $("select[name='make']").val();
    var printData = '<table width="960" border="0" align="center"> <tr> <td colspan="2"><div class="logo-print"></div></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2"><div align="center">Report</div></td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td width="260">Vin:</td> <td width="700"><b>'+ vin +'</b></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Make:</td> <td><b>'+ make +'</b></td> </tr> </table>';
    $(".printed-div").append(printData);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's too late for your answer but it could help someone else, who are searching for this.

before-

```
win.print();
```

place below code.

```
 $(win).load(function(){
        
});
```