# Bootstrap Modal Image Background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Just want to ask if it is possible to have a background image in my modal? I've tried searching but I only see background related things on modal which refers to the page itself. What I want is my modal box to have an image background on it. Or change it color? Thanks. I'm not that good in CSS. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310324/javascript-print-in-a-new-window-wont-display-images/39426586#39426586 Maybe this link would help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want an image in your modals body you can use

```
.modal-body {
   background-image: url(path/to/image);
}
```

Or if you want it behind your modal you can use

```
.modal-backdrop {
   background-image: url(path/to/image);
}
```

Comment: Modal body only puts the image as the background on the body (the middle of the modal if you will). Backdrop covers whats behind the modal popup. Is there a way to replace the entire modal background with an image (such that the header/footer are also under that single image)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `background-image: url(path/to/your/image);`

```js
$('#myModal').modal()
```

```css
.modal-body {
    background-image: url('http://myfunnymemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Doge-Meme-Lion-In-All-Its-Majestic-Glory.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the bootstrap from

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You will need to edit your

```
<div class="modal-content">
    ...
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="modal-content modal-popout-bg">
```

css:

```
.modal .modal-popout-bg {
    background-image: url("http://somepic.com/somepic.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got required results by below code, may be helpful for someone:

For showing fitting image only in body:

```css
.modal-body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("./bg_image.png");
}
```

For showing fitting image in Complete Modal (including header and footer):

```css
.modal-content {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("./bg_image.png");
}
```

Edit: Modal I used was standard one directly copied from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)